# How to initialize the blockchain correctly?

Tags: nodeos, blockchains

I am trying to initialize the blockchain using

`nodeos --genesis-json /home/nodeos/genesis-test.json --config-dir /home/nodeos/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config --delete-all-blocks`

but I am getting an error.

It says that there is a std::exception.  I don't understand why this is happening? Could anybody please explain?

I will attach a screenshot of the error for better understanding.[image]
**EDIT**

This is my config.ini

```
# ANSIBLE MANAGED FILE, YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST!

http-server-address = 127.0.0.1:8889

# Maximum size (in MB) of the chain state database (eosio::chain_plugin)
chain-state-db-size-mb = 200000

# The public endpoint of a peer node to connect to. Use multiple p2p-peer-address options as needed to compose a network. (eosio::net_plugin)

# The name supplied to identify this node amongst the peers. (eosio::net_plugin)
agent-name = "EOS2"

# Maximum number of clients from which connections are accepted, use 0 for no limit (eosio::net_plugin)
max-clients = 50

verbose-http-errors = true
http-validate-host = false

# Plugin(s) to enable, may be specified multiple times
plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::history_plugin
plugin = eosio::history_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::http_plugin
plugin = eosio::db_size_api_plugin

plugin = eosio::net_api_plugin

plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin
contracts-console = true
access-control-allow-origin = *
mongodb-queue-size = 256
mongodb-uri = mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/EOS2

plugin = eosio::net_plugin
p2p-peer-address = 127.0.0.1:8888


read-mode = read-only
mongodb-update-via-block-num = true
mongodb-store-blocks = false
mongodb-store-transactions = false
mongodb-store-transaction-traces = false


#filter-on=*
```

Comment: I am getting the same exception while writing just `nodeos`

Comment: Can you paste your `nodeos` config.ini and the `genesis-test.json` if you modified it?

Comment: @netuoso-EOSTitan I have pasted my config.ini could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error because, setting up of the P2P connection was wrong.

For properly setting up the P2P connection between any two nodes, regardless of them being producer or non producer nodes follow the following steps in your code. *(For your information, I had set up a producer node and a non producer node)*

**Node 1**:

```
plugin = eosio::net_plugin
http-server-address = 127.0.0.1:port_1
p2p-listen-endpoint = 127.0.0.1:port_A
p2p-peer-address = 127.0.0.1:port_B
```

**Node 2**:

```
plugin = eosio::net_plugin
http-server-address = 127.0.0.1:port_2
p2p-listen-endpoint = 127.0.0.1:port_B
p2p-peer-address = 127.0.0.1:port_A
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by deleting all data on **~/.local/share/eosio** and on **/usr/opt/eosio** and **~/eosio-wallet**.

I then executed `pkill nodeos` and `pkill keosd` on the terminal.

After that I restarted the nodeos :

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --access-control-allow-origin='*' --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false --verbose-http-errors >> nodeos.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: You mean the data directory inside ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data or the entire nodeos directory itself?

Comment: Do you have to delete /usr/opt/eosio or can it work by just deleting the folder in .local?

Comment: In my case it didn't work by only deleting **~/.local/share/eosio** folder. And for the first question i think it doesn't matter, but i deleted the entire nodeos folder.